# JasperException (File not found) randomly occuring

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a problem in my java web application (java 6 and tomcat 6) and I don't know how to solve it:

In a servlet, I'm fowarding a request to a JSP. That JSP includes some other JSPs. From time to time, one of these JSPs cannot be found although nothing has changed and the JSP file is still there. Which of the included JSPs cannot be found seems to be completely random. The following exception is thrown in the servlet:

```
Exception: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: 

javax.servlet.ServletException: File &quot;/theme/shared/shared-styles.jsp&quot; not found
Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:527)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:401)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
web.servlet.MainEntryServlet.processRequest(MainEntryServlet.java:39)
web.servlet.MainEntryServlet.doGet(MainEntryServlet.java:75)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:465)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The servlet itself is not very complex:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/theme/mytheme/index.jsp").forward(request, response);        
    } catch (Exception exc) {
      System.out.print(exc);
    }
  }
```

In the "/theme/mytheme/index.jsp" all JSPs are included this way:

```
<jsp:include flush="true" page="../shared/shared-styles.jsp"/>
```

I can't find a reason why it works in 99% of the cases and fails randomly from time to time.

**Update:**
I corrected the path of the index.jsp. I just made a mistake when I copied the code into the textarea.

Fullpath to index.jsp:
/theme/mytheme/index.jsp

Fullpath to shared-styles.jsp
/theme/shared/shared-styles.jsp

Comment: could you show full path for shared-styles.jsp"??

Comment: @stebeg is this still happening? if not, have you found out why it fails?

Answer (score 0):

Your absolute path may cause the problem , why dont you replace it with the [`${request.contextPath}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath())

it will always point to root of your application

Comment: I guess it won't make a difference. The path in the jsp:include has to be absolute or relative to the path of the jsp that's including it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related with your servlet. 

 Error is can't find your include jsp page.
Below changes will be advantages I think.

```
<jsp:include flush="true" page="../theme/shared/shared-styles.jsp"/>
```

Comment: That was not the problem. I just postet a wrong path. I updated the original post.

Comment: still not related.I mean if your full path is /theme/shared/shared-styles.jsp, please change your include to <jsp:include flush="true" page="../theme/shared/shared-styles.jsp"/>.

Comment: This doesn't work. The path to the JSP which I want to include must be absolute or relative to the JSP the servlet forwards to. The index.jsp is at /theme/mytheme/index.jsp. With your recomanded change, I would try to include /theme/theme/shared/shared-styles.jsp.